# ListBox throwing ArgumentOutOfRangeException after BindingSource update

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, listbox

I'm getting this exception when trying to select the new item added to a listbox via its bindingsource.

This is the BindingSource with a DataSource of custom objects

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource() { DataSource = myObjectsList };
listbox.DataSource = bs;
listbox.DisplayMember = "MyObjectProperty";
```

When i add a new item to the BindingSource the listbox updates but i can't select the new item

```
bs.Add(new MyObject());
int newItemIndex = listbox.Items.Count - 1; // this returns the right index of the new added item
listbox.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
```

Here i get the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException (InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.)

If i disable debug breaking in System exceptions the program goes on and the item get selected, but i can't understand why i'm getting that error if the listbox actually has the item.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because in WPF stuff happens asyncronously. If you tried to select your new item by assigning it as `SelectedItem` you would find that it probably wouldn't be selected. You can questions regarding this behaviour on `TabControl`. The reason is that just because you've added the item to the datasource that doesn't mean that the control has rendered and shown the item in the GUI. It needs to do some stuff like generate container (`ListBoxItem` probably) and if that hasn't happened then the item isn't truly added yet. So when you set the `SelectedIndex` you get the error.

tl;dr: The item hasn't been added in the GUI and as such your index is invalid. Just because the backing collection has the item that doesn't mean that it's really there ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think my problem here is somehow different: following your suggestion, i've made some further debug and this is what i get: if i add the new item like described and i don't programmatically select it, then every time i select it or leave it (at runtime), i always get that error, like if the item actually doesn't exist.

Comment: What happens if you use ``SelectedItem`` instead of ``SelectedIndex``?